# Did Giyu Tomioka meet the Hand / Morphed Demon during final selection?

Tags: demon-slayer

As we know this ugly looking demon https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Hand_Demon is captured by Urokodaki during the Edo period. Later this demon grows hatred toward Urokodaki and has killed every Urokodaki's disciples during final selection, even almost kills Tanjiro. Urokodaki seems so happy when he sees Tanjiro comeback home safely unlike his other death disciples.

But what about the watter pillar Giyu Tomioka? As far as I know he's also the disciple of Urokodaki (same breath style). The hand demon says that Sabito and Makomo (death people who trained Tanjiro during training) are the strongest among all, not Giyu. Did Giyu meet and survive the hand demon or was he just lucky to not encounter this powerful demon during selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [wiki](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Giyu_Tomioka/Relationships);

> while Sabito is long dead before the series started, both him and Sabito were best friends as they went through similar situations of losing their family to Demons and bonded well. Later during the Final Selection Exam, Sabito died at the hands of the Hand Demon trying to save his life and others who participated in the exam. Sabito's death caused Giyu to feel so much guilt to the point where he doubted his own abilities as a pillar and rescinds abandoning his position as the Water Pillar.

Answer (score 0):

giyu did incounter the demon that killed both makomo and sabito during final selection. He was ingured by that demon and saved by sabito who killed almost all the demons in the mountain. Sabito went back to go kill the demon but his sword broke in half and he had his head crushed by the demon and was killed. Makomo saw and fell into a rage and lost control of her motions and had her limbs ripped off